# Is it ok to have multiple primefaces socket tag on a page

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, primepush

Is it fine to have multiple  tags with different channel on a page, for me it never worked.
Is it a good use of prime push, Or is there any alternative to receive server push messages from multiple channels on a page. Here is piece of sample code what i have tried

```
<h:form>
  <p:socket channel="/pushMessages/#{session.id}">
     <p:ajax event="message" update=":navigation-form"/>
  </p:socket>
  <p:socket channel="/pushMessages/cart/#{session.id}">
   <p:ajax event="message" update=":message-form"/>
  </p:socket>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Should work. Any errors? Weird behaviour? Only the first working? Or the last? And what PF version did you use?

Comment: When I tried to have multiple sockets per page (long-polling), request and responses take a very long time (sometimes more than 10 minutes). With websockets its fine but I'm having issues proxying it via Apache. I'm using PF 5.3 and Atmosphere 2.4.4. Did you have the same symptoms as well?

Comment: It never worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Yes this works for me without a problem in PrimeFaces 6.2 (keep in mind that `p:push` is deprecated and the JSF 2.3 websockets is advised